# Why is jQuery Ajax call not working on Azure?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, azure

I have a jQuery Ajax methods and every Ajax call is not working on Azure. The code works fine in local environment, but as I said, on Azure does not work. Any ideas why?

### My code

```
var ProdutoDetalheViewModel = {
        'IdProdutoCategoria': $("#IdProdutoCategoria").val(),
        'Quantidade': $("#Quantidade").val()
    };

    var options = {};
    options.type = "POST";
    options.url = "/api/AtualizaDados";
    options.dataType = "JSON";
    options.cache = false;
    options.async = true;
    contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    options.data = ProdutoDetalheViewModel;

    options.beforeSend = function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN", $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
        $("#img").addClass("image");
        $("#loader").show();
    };

    options.success = function (data) {

        $("#loader").hide();
    };

    options.error = function () {
        $("#img").removeClass("image");
    };
    $.ajax(options);
```

### The Ajax calls the following method

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("/api/AtualizaDados")]
        public async Task<ProdutoDetalheViewModel> AtualizaDados(ProdutoDetalheViewModel produtoVW)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await _IAppProduto.AtualizaPrecoProduto(produtoVW);

                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Erro ao atualizar dados do produto.");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is your contentType intentionally unused?

Comment: This is hosted in azure, so you are accessing this via the browser, right? If so, use the network tab in Chrome developer tools to confirm that the browser is attempting to hit the correct endpoint.

Comment: whats the error you get in your browser console?

Comment: The error on browser console is about jquery.validate. That is, in local environment my current culture is ok, in this case, the local currency format (R$). But, working on azure, it appears as ($). Maybe could be it.

Comment: @Steve No, I will remove.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mode' of undefined at Function.a.ajaxPrefilter.a.ajax (jquery.validate.min.js?v=-BEKmIvQ6IsL8sHcvidtDrNOdZO3C9LtFPtF2H0dOHI:4)

Answer (score 0):

Now is working. I was using jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js, so I changed to jquery-3.5.1.min.js. Thanks for the help guys.